# Does a MemoryMappedFile with a single writer require synchronization

Tags: c#, web-services, synchronization, memory-mapped-files

I have a web service that processes Excel files (previously uploaded to the server), which involves a lot of database updates, and takes quite a while. I'd like to provide another web service that can be called to check the progress of this process. It would take the ID of the process (likely a GUID) as input and return an `int` (0-100) indicating the progress.

My thought is that the long-running service could create a memory-only `MemoryMappedFile` (MMF)—only `sizeof(int)` bytes would be needed—where it would, at some interval, report its progress. The "progress" service could then open the MMF, read the `int`, and report back to the caller.

I have two questions. First, I don't have much experience with MMFs, so is there some pitfall here that I'm possibly unaware of? Secondly, and more to the point, is synchronization necessary in this scenario, given that there will only be a single writer? After searching a bit, I wasn't able to discover if `MemoryMappedViewAccessor.Write` is atomic for `int`s.

Comment: Consider not using shared memory. Instead, send a request to the processing app and receive the progress as a response. Use a high-level protocol such as HTTP. Both http server and client are built-in to .NET as easy to use classes.

Comment: @usr: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. Both web services will be called by the same client (using jQuery). It will work something like this: 1) call service A to start processing the file and await response, 2) immediately start polling service B for progress (a progress bar on the web page will be updated). As soon as the call to service A returns (i.e., processing is complete) it stops polling service B.

Comment: What kind of web services are these? WebAPI, WCF based?

Comment: @marceln: I'm not sure how that matters, but I'm using ServiceStack.

Comment: Because I wanted to suggest `SignalR` for reporting progress **back** to the clients. I also recommend that the long-running process stores the progress in a database, not in a file, from where your SignalR based process will read/check it and then dispatch it to the corresponding client.

Comment: The MMF solution seems going a step further and not necessary. It's not really for this (sharing an int).

Comment: SignalR may be a better alternative to polling. But the question is about communicating between two web service calls, and the database seems overkill IMO. The MMF is entirely in memory. There is no physical backing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure at first since I haven't used MMFs for IPC before, but I tested this now using [the samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx).

The short answer is NO, synchronization is not necessary (and this makes sense if you think about it). You have below both samples - writer process and reader process, as console apps.

The only catch is that you want to either reset the cursor position in the write/read streams to 0 after each read/write or alternatively create a view map for the first 32 bits. Not sure if the second works (most likely not and you still have to reset the file pointer).

**Writer process:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 10000))
        {
            int i = 0;
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    while (i++ < 10000)
                    {
                        writer.Write(i);
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**Reader process:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap"))
            {
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        int value = 0;
                        while (value != 10000)
                        {
                            value = reader.ReadInt32();
                            Console.WriteLine("Process A says: {0}", value);
                            stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            Thread.Sleep(20);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Memory-mapped file does not exist. Run Process A first.");
        }
    }
```

I deliberately made the reader wait less between reads than the writer waits between writes to make sure there are no coincidences.

The output is as expected, although didn't wait for it to finish:

```
Process A says: 85
Process A says: 85
Process A says: 85
Process A says: 86
Process A says: 86
Process A says: 87
Process A says: 87
Process A says: 87
Process A says: 88
Process A says: 88
Process A says: 89
Process A says: 89
Process A says: 89
Process A says: 90
Process A says: 90
Process A says: 91
Process A says: 91
Process A says: 91
Process A says: 92
Process A says: 92
Process A says: 93
Process A says: 93
Process A says: 93
Process A says: 94
```

That being said, I still don't recommend MMF. From your description, you can store without issues the progress statically (maybe in a concurrent collection) in the service that reports the progress. You can solve this by only exposing another endpoint or method which can be called by the second service to update the progress for a specific client/file. When it's done, it just tells it to remove it from memory.